# Why does it say my tree has no branch lengths when it does?

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I am trying to calculate phylogenetic signal using the phylosig function from phytools, but I get this error:

```
Error in vcv.phylo(tree) : the tree has no branch lengths
```

However, when I check my tree, it says it does have branch lengths!

```
> MCC_genus_tree

Phylogenetic tree with 1160 tips and 1159 internal nodes.

Tip labels:
    Anolis, Ornithorhynchus, Zaglossus, Tachyglossus, Rhynchocyon, Elephantulus, ...

Rooted; includes branch lengths.
```

What is going on? Any help would be appreciated.

---

EDIT:

My tree is a MCC tree downloaded from vertlife.

Comment: Help us help you. Can you provide an example? Possibly a smaller version of your tree that has the same problem?  How about the code that you used to generate the tree? It is hard to respond to just an error message without knowing how you got to that message.

Comment: Hi G5W, thank you - I realise this was a rather poorly written question! I have updated the question (but also found the answer). Thanks for taking a look, though!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is I goofed. My data had no names, so phylosig dropped all my tips!

This is how I fixed it:

```
data_with_names <- data_without_names$trait
names(data_with_names) <- data_with_names$species_names
```